# jQuery expanding menu

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have this html code:

```
<ul id="nav">
    <li>Heading 1
        <ul>
            <li>Sub page A</li>
            <li>Sub page B</li>
            <li>Sub page C</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>Heading 2
        <ul>
            <li>Sub page D</li>
            <li>Sub page E</li>
            <li>Sub page F</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

With this JS code:

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav>li>ul').hide();
    $('#nav>li').mouseover(function(){
        if ($('#nav ul:animated').size() == 0) {
            $heading = $(this);
            $expandedSiblings = $heading.siblings().find('ul:visible');
            if ($expandedSiblings.size() > 0) {
                $expandedSiblings.slideUp(500, function(){
                    $heading.find('ul').slideDown(500);
                });
            }
            else {
                $heading.find('ul').slideDown(1000);
            }
        }
    });
})
```

For now the code works this way: When click on Heading 1, menu is expanded. When click on Heading 2, heading2 submenu menu is expanded and heading 1 submenu is closed. I need to rework it to this: Submenus must be closed automatically on mouseout. 
Can somebody help me?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a slightly different animation (simulateous sliding, rather than one after the other), but if it's an option [`.hover()`](http://api.jquery.com/hover/) which uses [`mouseenter`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/) and [`mouseleave`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/) rather than [`mouseover`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/) and [`mouseout`](http://api.jquery.com/mouseout/) (which fire on children) would be much simpler, like this:

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav>li>ul').hide();
    $('#nav>li').hover(function(){
        $(this).find('ul').slideToggle(500)
               .siblings().find('ul:visible').slideUp(500);
    });
})
```

Comment: nice one, just in case anybody wanted to play with it. http://jsfiddle.net/VFXQW/

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you want to keep your original setup and add the mouseout functionality, but you find that the `mouseout` fires before the `mouseover`, you can use the ol' `setTimeout` trick:

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav>li>ul').hide();
    $('#nav>li').mouseover(function(){
        if ($('#nav ul:animated').size() == 0) {
            $heading = $(this);
            $expandedSiblings = $heading.siblings().find('ul:visible');
            if ($expandedSiblings.size() > 0) {
                $expandedSiblings.slideUp(500, function(){
                    $heading.find('ul').slideDown(500);
                });
            }
            else {
                $heading.find('ul').slideDown(1000);
            }
        }
    }).mouseout(function() {
         var $heading = $(this);
         window.setTimeout(function() {
            if ($('#nav ul:animated').size() == 0) {
                $heading.find('ul').slideUp(500);
            }
        }, 0);
    });
})
```

Comment: It works but the submenu should not be closed when mouse is over him

Answer (score 0):

Try this but you will probably have to add some delays to make a smooth user experience.

```
$(function(){
    $('#nav>li>ul').hide();
    $('#nav>li').hover(function(){
        $(this).children().slideDown(500);
    }, function(){
        $(this).children().slideUp(500);
    });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm doing it with the `.hover(function ()`  and  `.mouseLeave (function ()`  and it works wonderfully:

```
$('ul.expanded>li>ul').hide();
          $('ul.expanded>li').hover(function(){
             if ($('ul.expanded ul:animated').size() == 0) {
                 $heading = $(this);
                 $expandedSiblings = $heading.siblings().find('ul:visible');
             if ($expandedSiblings.size() > 0) {
                 $expandedSiblings.slideUp(1000, function(){
                 $heading.find('ul').slideDown(500);
                 });
             }
             else {
                 $heading.find('ul').slideDown(500);
                 }
             }
          }).mouseleave(function() {
                 var $heading = $(this);
                 window.setTimeout(function() {
                 if ($('ul.expanded ul:animated').size() == 0) {
                 $heading.find('ul').slideUp(1000);
                 }
             }, 0);
          });
```